# Temporal row at multiple times in EF

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to efficiently get the current row in a temporal table and a specific historical row with the same identity?  We want our app to show the current Repair information, but also show the history at the time the Claim was submitted.  We already know how to get the historical rows:

```
_db.ClaimsPortalRepairs.TemporalAsOf(submittedDateTimeUtc).Where(c => c.ClaimId == claimId)
```

That works great.  It gets all the Repairs for a Claim at the time the Claim was submitted.

This is my attempt to get the current Repairs and the originally submitted Repairs efficiently.

```
_db.ClaimsPortalRepairs.Where(r => r.ClaimId == claimId && !r.IsDeleted).Select(r =>
    new
    {
        Current = r,
        Original = r.Claim.IsSubmitted
            ? _db.ClaimsPortalRepairs
                .TemporalAsOf(r.Claim.SubmittedDateTimeUtc!.Value)
                .FirstOrDefault(rh => rh.RepairId == r.RepairId)
            : null
    }
)
```

Note that here, we're using the row id, RepairId, to join.

The error I get is:

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ClaimsPortalRepair]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1[Models.gwc.ClaimsPortalRepair]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Models.gwc.ClaimsPortalRepair] TemporalAsOf[ClaimsPortalRepair](Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1[Models.gwc.ClaimsPortalRepair], System.DateTime)' (Parameter 'arg0')
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, String methodParamName, String argumentParamName, Int32 index)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(MethodInfo method, Expression arg0, Expression arg1)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.VisitConditional(ConditionalExpression conditionalExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitNew(NewExpression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.ExtractParameters(Expression expression, Boolean clearEvaluatedValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.ExtractParameters(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExtractParameters(Expression query, IParameterValues parameterValues, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Boolean parameterize, Boolean generateContextAccessors)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Claims.Features.Claim.Features.Repairs.Controllers.GetRepairsController.Get(Int32 claimId) in C:\Users\xxx\GetRepairsController.cs:line 27
```

Comment: What `System.Dynamic` is doing here? Any additional extensions?